# One assert with multiple condition vs multiple assert

Tags: java, assert

In java, If I need to ensure multiple conditions, I can write in two ways as using single assert with all condition vs using separate assert for each condition.
Which one is better approach?

Example:
Suppose we have three condition need to be ensured as cond1, cond2, cond3.

Using single assert

`assert cond1 && cond2 && cond3;`

Using multiple assert

`assert cond1;`
`assert cond2;`
`assert cond3;`

Comment: I prefer one assert per condition. It is much more easier to find out why the assert fails

Comment: Does the person debugging your code (not necessarily you) need to know which condition caused the assert?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple assert statements.  One for each condition will help you easily determine which condition failed, in case there's a problem.

With a single assertion statement for all conditions, you will have to as a next step identify which condition failed. As test will just say that assertion failed but what exactly failed still needs to be determined.